# Tooltips using mpldatacursor in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have been pulling my hair out for a while over this. I am trying to use [`mpldatacursor`](https://github.com/joferkington/mpldatacursor/) along with `matplotlib` to provide a tooltip functionality on scatter plots. Each point has some data associated with it which I would like to show when the point is clicked.

Here is a minimal (not) working example:

```
import numpy as np
import mpldatacursor
import string
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Qt5Agg')
from matplotlib import pyplot as mpl

nations = ['Russia', 'America', 'China', 'France']
data = list()
idx = list()

np.random.seed(42) #Seed for repeatability

# Random data
for (id, nation) in enumerate(nations):
    for i in range(0,10):
        data.append((id+1)*np.random.random((2,1)))
        name = list(string.ascii_uppercase[20:])
        np.random.shuffle(name)
        idx.append(nation + '-' + ''.join(name))

mpl.figure()
data = np.squeeze(np.asarray(data))
m, n = 0, 9

# Plot by group
for (id,nation) in enumerate(nations):
    mpl.scatter(data[m:n,0] , data[m:n,1] , label=nation)
    m = n + 1
    n += 10

formatter = lambda **kwargs: ', '.join(kwargs['point_label'])
mpl.legend()
mpldatacursor.datacursor(formatter=formatter, point_labels=idx)
mpl.show(block=True)
```

But when I do this, the tooltips don't match the legends. Further only labels starting with `Russia` and `USA` show up in the plot. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually you would have your data in a table or, for the sake of the example, several lists. One would hence probably create a single scatter plot from the data columns and use a mapping of names to numbers to create the colors in the scatter.

Then one can use the matplotlib `pick_event` to get the data out of the respective list, given the index of the point on which the click happened.

This all does not require any external packages like datacursor.

```
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(42)
import string
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

nations = ['Russia', 'America', 'China', 'France']

#Create lists data, nat, idx
nat = np.random.choice(nations, 50)
data = np.random.rand(50,2)
strings = ["".join(np.random.choice(list(string.ascii_uppercase), 7)) for _ in range(50)]
idx = ["{}-{}".format(n,w) for n,w in zip(nat,strings)]

labels, i = np.unique(nat, return_inverse=True)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()


scatter = ax.scatter(data[:,0], data[:,1], c=i, cmap="RdYlGn", picker=5)

rect = lambda c: plt.Rectangle((0,0),1,1, color=scatter.cmap(scatter.norm(c)))
handles = [rect(c) for c in np.unique(i)]
plt.legend(handles, labels)

#Create annotation
annot = ax.annotate("", xy=(0,0), xytext=(-20,20),textcoords="offset points",
                    bbox=dict(boxstyle="round", fc="w"),
                    arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="->"))
annot.set_visible(False)

#Create event handler
def onpick(evt):
    if evt.artist == scatter:
        ind = evt.ind[0]
        annot.xy = (data[ind])
        annot.set_text(idx[ind])
        annot.set_visible(True)
    if evt.mouseevent.button == 3:
        annot.set_visible(False)
    fig.canvas.draw_idle()

fig.canvas.mpl_connect("pick_event", onpick)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: This does answer the question completely, but in my case scatter() is just one of many methods that a class I am implementing and its just easier to use `mpldatacursor` since it packages many features into a module.

Answer (score 2):

The issue was that each call to `scatter` by `matplotlib` was creating a new artist object. The workaround is based on the doc-string in the [source code](https://github.com/joferkington/mpldatacursor/blob/master/mpldatacursor/datacursor.py).

> point_labels : sequence or dict, optional
>               Labels for "subitems" of an artist, passed to the formatter
>               function as the `point_label` kwarg.  May be either a single
>               sequence (used for all artists) or a dict of artist:sequence pairs.

It does involve the import of a protected matplotlib module/member. This seems to work as I want:

---

```
import numpy as np
import mpldatacursor
import string
import matplotlib
from matplotlib import _pylab_helpers as pylab_helpers
matplotlib.use('Qt5Agg')
from matplotlib import pyplot as mpl

nations = ['Russia', 'America', 'China', 'France']
data = list()
idx = list()

np.random.seed(42)

for (index, nation) in enumerate(nations):
    for i in range(0,10):
        data.append((index + 1) * np.random.random((2, 1)))
        name = list(string.ascii_uppercase[20:])
        np.random.shuffle(name)
        idx.append(nation + '-' + ''.join(name))

data = np.squeeze(np.asarray(data))
m, n = 0, 9
artist_labels = list()
mpl.figure()

for (index, nation) in enumerate(nations):
    mpl.scatter(data[m:n,0] , data[m:n,1] ,label=nation)
    artist_labels.append(idx[m:n])
    m = n + 1
    n += 10

def plotted_artists(ax):
    all_artists = (ax.lines + ax.patches + ax.collections
               + ax.images + ax.containers)
    return all_artists

def formatter (**kwargs):
    return kwargs['point_label'].pop()

managers = pylab_helpers.Gcf.get_all_fig_managers()
figs = [manager.canvas.figure for manager in managers]
axes = [ax for fig in figs for ax in fig.axes]
artists = [artist for ax in axes for artist in plotted_artists(ax)]

my_dict = dict(zip(artists, artist_labels))
mpldatacursor.datacursor(formatter=formatter, point_labels=my_dict)

mpl.legend()
mpl.show(block=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you simply want names, this seems to work correctly if you change the `mpldatacursor.datacursor` call to use `'{label}'` as in the first [example](https://pypi.org/project/mpldatacursor/) on the `mpldatacursor` website,

```
mpldatacursor.datacursor(formatter='{label}'.format)
```

I think the problem is with `kwargs` and the lambda function. If you want further data in your tooltip, it may be best to add this to the label on `plt.scatter`, using a separate call for each point, e.g.

```
import numpy as np
import mpldatacursor
import string
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Qt5Agg')
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

nations = ['Russia', 'America', 'China', 'France']
cDict =  {'Russia':'r', 'America':'b', 'China':'g', 'France':'c'}

np.random.seed(42) #Seed for repeatability

# Random data
for (id, nation) in enumerate(nations):
    for i in range(0,10):
        x = (id+1)*np.random.random((2,1))
        name = list(string.ascii_uppercase[20:])
        np.random.shuffle(name)
        plt.scatter(x[0], x[1], c=cDict[nation], label=nation + '-' + ''.join(name))

mpldatacursor.datacursor(formatter='{label}'.format)
plt.show(block=True)
```

Comment: No I really do want the whole string in `idx` , not just the country name, i.e I want to be able to distinguish points one step more than what can be simply done with legends.

Comment: I see... I'm no expert with `mpldatacursor` but as `matplotlib` scatter creates a collection, with a single label (for use in legends), you'd need to do a separate plot per point (added an example above) so each has its own label (or keep a separate list in the same order as your plotted data, which strikes me as potentially problematic).

Comment: The problem is each call to `scatter` creates a different `matplotlib` artist.

Comment: Your answer is fine, except you can't use a call to legend anymore. There is workaround that lets you do both. I posted it as an answer.

Comment: Yeah, not ideal for efficiency but I can't see another solution. You could create a range of [patch objects](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.Patch.html#matplotlib.patches.Patch) which can each have a label and add them to a collection manually.