# Change parameter based on clicked Artist in a scatter plot in python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a scatter plot in python with the option `picker=True`

Now I want to open another python Script with a parameter based on the point I picked.

I do have a working event

```
self.fig.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', self.onpick)
def onpick(self, event):
    artist = event.artist
    print("Hello")
...
# The scatter plot is created with
plt.scatter(data[:, 0], data[:, 1], cmap=cmap, c=data[:, 2], s=100, picker=True)
```

Always when I click on a scatter point python prints `Hello`.

Now I would love to add a simple information to each artist (e.g. the order they were created as an `int`), so when I click it, I can access this information and use it as my parameter for the python script I want to open on click.

An other (worse) idea would be, to get the Position of that artist in my plot and then calculate my parameter based on the Position of that artist.

Sadly, I couldn't find any information if one of the ideas is possible. I found at https://matplotlib.org/2.0.0/users/artists.html that artists have an x and an y Value, but I couldn't access it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I happen to have answered a question with exactly that just a couple of hours ago: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50843736/4124317

Answer (score 0):

You could try expanding on something like

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def onpick(event):
    artist = event.artist
    for scatter_plot in scatter_plots:
        if artist is scatter_plot.plot:
            print(scatter_plot.order)

class MyScatterPlot():
    def __init__(self, order):
        self.order = order
        self.plot = None

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

scatter_plot1 = MyScatterPlot("first")
scatter_plot2 = MyScatterPlot("second")

scatter_plot1.plot = ax.scatter([1,1,1],[1,2,3], picker=True)
scatter_plot2.plot = ax.scatter([3,3,3],[1,2,3], picker=True)

scatter_plots = [scatter_plot1, scatter_plot2]

fig.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', onpick)

fig.show()
```

This idea is based on the fact that you can compare your picked `artist` to the objects returned by the `scatter` function.